# Spring Boot MongoRepository unit testing using pre-installed MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-repositories

I have a regular Spring Boot application (1.3.2) with MongoDB using `MongoRepository`.

I would like to write an integration test for one of my endpoints that gets the data from the MongoDB. As far as I see from the [Spring Boot 1.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.3-release-notes) Spring has auto-configuration for [Embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) (`de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`). However, I cannot figure out from Spring and flapdoodle documentation on how to write an integration test that would use already installed version of MongoDB on my filesystem.

So far my integration test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class) // my application class
@WebAppConfiguration
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        myRepository.save(new MyEntity());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // here I will fire requests against the endpoint
    }
}
```

I have added two dependencies with `test` scope: `spring-boot-starter-test` and `de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`. So when I run the test, I can see that flapdoodle attempts to download version of MongoDB, but fails since I am behind the proxy. But I do not want to download any versions, I want it to use my locally installed MongoDB. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: did you done with these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your locally installed MongoDB (not recommended, since then the tests depend on a particular DB that can get into a dirty state), then you shouldn't be pulling in the embedded MongoDB.

I believe this config will do what you're asking for, though (seems to work in my Spring Boot 1.3.5 test):

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class TestConfig
{
    @Primary
    @Bean
    MongoClient mongoClient()
    {
        try
        {
            return new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I suspect you would be better off properly configuring the proxy and using the embedded mongoDB in your tests. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388917/junit-test-cases-using-embed-mongodb-de-flapdoodle-embed-mongo/30775242#30775242) for hints on how to do that.